# Anyone please explain me this question, I din get it what exactly I have to code?

Tags: python, function

ALMOST THERE: Given an integer n, return True if n is within 10 of either 100 or 200

almost_there(90) --> True

almost_there(104) --> True

almost_there(150) --> False

almost_there(209) --> True

NOTE: abs(num) returns the absolute value of a number

Comment: you just need to do abs(n-100) and abs (n-200) and if any of those are less or equal 10 then True. Please try some code and let us know if/where you get stuck.

Comment: this is checking if given number is in the range of +or- 10 of 100 or 200

Comment: Not me, but I would say that such questions have no value in answering them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if n in range(x, y):`. As an example, the range 90 to 100 is applied in the code below. If it falls in this range, it sets `almost_there` to True. Otherwise it sets it to False.

```
def almostThere(n):
    if n in range(90,100):
        almost_there = True
    else :
        almost_there = False
```

The full solution to your problem would then be:

```
def almostThere(n):
    if n in range(90,110) or n in range (100,110) or n in range (190,210):
        almost_there = True
    else :
        almost_there = False
```

Answer (score 0):

abs() returns you the absolute number -/+ wont matter
Is it in range of the number 10, for the numbers 100 and 200
then its valid! so return true.

```
print("your number: ")
my_number = int(input())

def almost_there(my_number):
    if abs(100 - my_number) <= 10 or abs(200 - my_number) <= 10:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(f"almost_there({my_number}) --> {almost_there(my_number)}")
```

So if you substract your number, you give in input with the value 100, or 200 and it is within the number 10, so return True.

abs(100 - my_number) ..100 - your number <= 10 .. is it within 10, function returns True if true, otherwise False